# How can I use iterator to pass the value in a recursive function in c++?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, iterator

If I run the code as below then it crashes for the inputs. But if I do not use the iterator and use the code written in the comment section(in `DFS()` function) then it gets run well and doesn't crash anymore. I can't understand why this code is getting crashes by iterator.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

vector<pair<int, int> > graph[30009];
vector<pair<int, int> >:: iterator it;

long long int far;
int  visit[30001], last;

void DFS(int vertex, long long int edge)
{
    if(edge > far){
        far = edge;
        last = vertex;
    }
    /*for(int i = 0; i < graph[vertex].size(); i++){
        int node = graph[vertex][i].first;
        int weight = graph[vertex][i].second;
        if(visit[node] == 0){
        visit[node] = 1;
        DFS(node, edge+weight);
    }
}*/
    for(it = graph[vertex].begin(); it != graph[vertex].end(); it++){
        int node = it->first;
        int weight = it->second;
        if(visit[node] == 0){
            visit[node] = 1;
            DFS(node, edge+weight);
        }
    }

return;

}
int main()
{
    int T, n,u,v,w;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(int i = 1; i <= T; i++){
            far = 0;

        memset(visit, 0, sizeof(visit));
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(int j = 0; j < 30001; j++)
            graph[j].clear();
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w);
            graph[u].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
            graph[v].push_back(make_pair(u,w));
        }
        visit[0] = 1;
        DFS(0, 0);

        memset(visit, 0, sizeof(visit));
        visit[last] = 1;
        DFS(last, 0);

        printf("Case %d: %lld\n", i, far);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why `it` is global.

Comment: Using global variables in recursive functions is very frequently wrong. Using global variables as iteration variables is also usually wrong. You're breaking both guidelines here.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

`it` is global, so every call to `DFS` is using the same `it`. So when you

```
for(it = graph[vertex].begin(); it != graph[vertex].end(); it++){
```

`it` is "pointed" at a different `vector` to iterate. When `DFS` returns, the calling `DFS` tries to carry on where it left off with the wrong `vector` AND that `vector` has already been iterated to `end()`. `it` will be incremented out of range, and once that happens any use is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In addition `it != graph[vertex].end()` can only be true by freak accident because they are both referring to different `vector`s, so the loop wanders further off into uncharted territories and eventually this bug is manifested, for the asker at any rate, in a crash.

## Solution

Remove

```
vector<pair<int, int> >:: iterator it;
```

and replace

```
for(it = graph[vertex].begin(); it != graph[vertex].end(); it++)
```

with

```
for(auto it = graph[vertex].begin(); it != graph[vertex].end(); it++)
```

or

```
for(vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = graph[vertex].begin(); 
    it != graph[vertex].end(); 
    it++)
```

depending on the target C++ standard.

## Caveat

This only resolves the most visible problem. There may be others. I have not checked.